# xmlhttp request in javascript file causing errors

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file which has some code somewhat like this:

```
var Slide =     
{   

    init: function()
    {
        var thumbs = new Array();
        thumbs = Core.getElementsByClass("thumb-img");
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++)
        {
            Core.addEventListener(thumbs[i], "click",  (function( j){return function(){Slide.showImage(j);/*alert(j);*/};})(i));

        }
    },
```

Now, I am trying to pass xmlhttp objects in this javascript file.
I am adding the following just above the `init: function()`...

```
var xmlhttp;

function getVote(int)
{
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }
var value = int;
alert(value);
var url="user_submit.php";
url=url+"?vote="+int;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  {
  document.getElementById("captionbox").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var objXMLHttp=null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return objXMLHttp;
}
```

...but firebug gives me error:
`missing : after property id var xmlhttp;\n`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, there is a security flaw in your code--any site on the internet can submit a vote on behalf of a user of your page like this:

<script>
new Image().src = 'http://yoursite.com/user_submit.php?vote=4&sid = ' + Math.random();
</script>

Make sure to read this before you launch your site: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001175.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's invalid syntax - you can't have code just floating around in an object. The easiest way to do that would be to just move that code outside the Object.

A better way would be to have a function `initXhr()`, which is called by `init()`. That would contain the same code as you tried to put before `init`. Then, add at the end:

```
this.xmlHttp = xmlHttp;
```

Then, in other functions, use `this.xmlHttp`.

Comment: hwo do i access the variables outside the Slide function, inside it?

Comment: You should just be able to just use their name as usual, if you declared them with `var`.

Comment: but i am unable to. i want to use a var i made in getVote() in the Slide->init() function. how do i do that?

Comment: Here, you must declare the var *outside* `getVote()`, then leave off the var when using it in getVote(). See http://pastebin.com/m87d7422

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting normal Javascript inside an object block.

Move the XMLHTTP code block above the line `var Slide =`.

If this doesn't help, please show us the entire file.